# How can I pass null from react native to java when I develop a module

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, module

I'm developing a native module for Android in React Native. I have two method with the same name but I can't use them in React Native because Java Script has not overloading directly. So I write a function which can get null as a paramater in React Native and try to handle it in Java.

React Native side:

```
    function a(arg=null){
       moduleName.b(arg)
    }
```

Java side:

```
public void b(@Nullable Boolean arg, final Promise promise){
  if(arg == null){
    c()
  }else{
    c(arg)
  }
}
```

Then I have not problem when I pass true or false to function a but when I pass nothing to funtion a I get an error on my phone like that:

[image: error]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to multiple things going wrong into code. Some areas which needs to look are:

- use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` in your Java code.
- try checking if your `getIntent()` function is not returning `null` intent , just before receiving intent from bundle.
- You are trying to check `Boolean` with `null` , that's why it's throwing `java.lang.Boolean` on a null object reference.

Comment: Because of boolean can't be null I can't even check if arg == null. It gives  error: incomparable types: boolean and <null>